# Add a method to an object in Grails and have it usable globally

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

I am attempting to add some string utility methods to the String class by utilizing Groovy's `metaclass` functionality. Right now I have something like this in my init closure in my BootStrap.groovy script:

```
String.metaClass.upper = {
   delegate.toUpperCase()
}
```

The problem is that this `upper` method is only available within the scope of the BootStrap...trying to use it anywhere else in the Grails app does not work and I get method missing errors.

Is there any way to make those methods available everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen in both testing and running contexts?  There is a bug where all `metaClass` changes get rolled back after each unit test: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8596

Comment: I haven't tried to use the methods in a test. I can see they don't exist when I try to load up a view where I'm using one of the methods I've added. However, if I put a break point right after the definition in BootStrap, I can add watches that use the methods I've added correctly, but as soon as they go out of scope I get method missing errors.

Comment: I tried your `String.upper()` example with a fresh grails 2.0 project and it works for me in both a controller and a view.  Can you post the whole `BootStrap.groovy` and the code you're using to call it?